# Ember.Select - optional optgroups

Tags: ember.js

At the moment I am using the `{{view Ember.Select}}` method to create a grouped select field quite easily, as follows:

```
{{view Ember.Select 
    name="car_manufacturer"
    contentBinding="car_manufacturers"
    optionGroupPath="country"
    optionValuePath="content.val"
    optionLabelPath="content.label"
}}
```

My question is, is there any way by which Ember.Select can create a select field that *doesn't* wrap the `<option>` tags for specific group name(s) in the `<optgroup>` tag?

e.g, produce markup like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>  
    ...
    <optgroup label="Germany">
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        ...
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Korea">
        <option value="kia">Kia</option>
        ...
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: have you found any solutions or workarounds?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data beforehand and send it into the option without the group path.

```
carsByCountry: function(){
  return this.sortBy('country'); 
}.property()
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IRIpAYo/1/edit

Comment: That completely misses the point.  Your jsbin doesn't create anything like what @TimCromwell was asking for.

Comment: I'm sorry I've offended you so much by attempting to help, his question is quite ambiguous, he asked "is there any way by which Ember.Select can create a select field that doesn't wrap the `<option>` tags for specific group name(s) in the <optgroup> tag"  I provided a way where his results were ordered by group, and doesn't wrap the `<option>` tags in the `<optgroup>` tag.